# Multiple images linked to a user's profile

Tags: sql, database, django, django-models

I have a user with a profile picture. The picture will be converted into two sizes: one which will be displayed for his profile (approx 200px. wide) and a smaller thumbnail that will be displayed in search results (approx 64 px. wide).

What would be the best way to construct the database and folder structure for this?

My two ideas for db structure are:

```
# 1)
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True,)
    avatar_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True,)

# 2) 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ...

class Avatar(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

Which one would be a better way to handle this? And what would be a good way to structure my image folder to easily separate and reference the two image sizes? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that the second option would actually be better. Potentially split out into a separate app altogether. I've found it's much better to keep functionality compartmentalized. keep everything related to your avatar in one app and keep the thumbnailing code etc part of that, as well as creating a template tag for displaying the avatar.

there might already be an app for that...

Comment: thanks for the response. And how would you organize the file structure for the two different images?

Comment: Theres two schools of thought. First you can create a thumbnails folder next to your images folder with an internal directory structure that is identical. I prefer the second, which would be to create a thumbs directory next to the file your thumbnailing, and keep the thumbnails in there. something like: upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/thumbs/'

Comment: would you ever want to create a separate folder for each user, e.g., upload_to='images/%s/%Y/%m/%d/thumbs/' %(username) ?

Comment: makes total sense to me. i honestly don't see a reason to have the dates in there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Sorl Thumbnail, upload one image and create the smaller version on the fly using Sorl's template tag(s). This would also save you from having to create another class. I've had a lot of success with this library, hope it helps you out.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorl-thumbnail/11.05.2

Comment: @Brandon: thanks for the response. I've only used PIL for image processing so far, but would creating thumbnails "on the fly" make Sorl much slower? For example, if I have a page of 50 users with 50 thumbnails.

Comment: The image only gets created once, then cached, so the first time this happens, there's going to be slightly more processing time to create the image. Honestly, I've never seen enough of a delay during this processing time to even notice. I've implemented it on just about every Django site I've ever built.

Comment: @Brandon: does Sorl require setting up a cache in Django?

Comment: No, it just creates a "cache" folder in the directory you've specified for static content to come out of.

Comment: @Brandon, in going through installation docs it says "sorl-thumbnail needs a Key Value Store for its operation. You can choose between a cached database which requires no special installation to your normal Django setup besides installing a proper cache like memcached or you can setup redis which requires a little bit more work." How would this work without setting up a cache?

Comment: Ah, my bad. The sites I typically build at home with Django are small, so I enable database caching early on in the project and set caching to dummy in a local_settings.py file when debugging, which is probably why Sorl has never complained about there not being a cache.

Comment: also checkout imagekit ( https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit ). Thumbnailing isn't hard though, you can look at my (nto well commented) code here: https://github.com/ehutch79/django-galleria/blob/master/galleria/models.py relevant lines start at 136